# having problems with Zend framework validators

Tags: zend-framework, validation, zend-validate

I'm having problem with custom builded validator that does not returns any error. I copied a file NotEmpty.php form folder **library/Zend/Validate**, rename class Zend_Validate_NotEmpty to My_Validate_EmailConfirmation and put it into folder **My/Validate**.

If I call this class like
**->setRequired(true)->addValidator('NotEmpty',true,array('messages' => array('isEmpty' => "bla")));**
I get the correct error, but if i call it like
**->setRequired(true)->addValidator('EmailConfirmation',true,array('mess ages' => array('isEmpty' => "bla")))->addPrefixPath('My_Validate','My/Validate/','validate');**
i get nothing...

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks is advanced for your answers...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set in your bootstrap file your new namespace?

```
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->registerNamespace('My');
```

Also, why not you just extends the NotEmpty validator instead of duplicate the class?